# Параметр в методе класса не видит, обьявленную, глобальную структуру

Tags: c++

Пробовал обьявлять внутри класса, эффект тот же.
Вот собственно класс с подключенным .h файлом, внутри которого обьявлены структуры

```
#ifndef CMENU_H_INCLUDED
#define CMENU_H_INCLUDED
/*cMenu.h*/
#include "../prog_constr/gGlobal.h"
#include "gGlobal.h"
void Switcher(menu_switch ** menu_caller, menu_switch * button_caller, Model * modela);


//#include "cModel.h"
void Button::status(bool clicked, menu_switch * menu_caller, Model * modela)
{
    b_status.dest.active=clicked;
    //if( seek_menu_in_m_list(  ) )//
Switcher(&menu_caller, &b_status, modela);
}

class Menu {
public:

    struct output { int place; void (*m_out)(); };
    struct input { int place; int (*m_in)(); };

    Menu(SDL_Window ** window, SDL_Renderer ** renderer);
    void setup(int ncodename, SDL_Window ** window, SDL_Renderer ** renderer);
    void add_button(int x,int y,int w,int h,int dest);

    void check_buttons();

    void input();
    void output();
    void connect_output(output out);//тут ошибка("error: 'output' does not name a type")
void connect_input(input in);//тут ошибка("error: 'input' does not name a type")

    void run(bool run);
    menu_switch get_p_status() { return &status; }

protected:
    SDL_Event e;
    int mx,my;
    menu_switch m_status; 
    vector<Button> butt; 
    Graf graf;  


    output out; //тут ошибка("error: output is not a type")
    input in;   //тут ошибка("error: input is not a type")
    SDL_Window ** swindow;
    SDL_Renderer ** srenderer;

//Model modela;
};
   ...код
#endif
```

Comment: И? Что мы должны увидеть в этом коде? О какой "глобальной структуре" идёт речь? Что такое "не видит"? Почему в вопросе ничего этого не приведено?

Comment: структуру(output и input) не видно в функциях void connect_input/output и в приватной зоне

Comment: Что значит "не видно"? Сообщение об ошибке в студию.

Comment: добавил комментарии к строкам где появляются ошибки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Частая ошибка. Вы объявили в своем классе методы `input` и `output`. В области видимости класса после этих объявлений методов имена `input` и `output` - это уже имена *методов*, а не имена классов (структур). Либо переименуйте методы, либо переименуйте структуры.

Если бы структуры были объявлены глобально, то ситуацию можно было бы исправить через использование имён вида `::input` и `::output` для ссылки на структуры.

В вашем текущем варианте ситуацию тоже можно исправить: через использование elaborate имён вида `struct input` и `struct output` для ссылки на ваши структуры.

Но лучше просто устранить конфликт имён.

Comment: мда, чувствую себя профаном, огромное спасибо за помощь, сейчас попробую поправить.

Comment: @gorgora98 Если разобрались, жмякните галочку слева от ответа чтобы отметить вопрос как решенный.